# Custom UITableViewCell button click

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In a UIViewController there is a UITableView which consists custom UITableViewCell with a UIButton.

When the user clicks the button (in the custom UITableViewCell), I want to display a message in the hosting UIViewController - **what is the right way to achieve that?** How should I notify the UIViewController that the button was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegation to tell the `UIViewController` that something happened in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what kind of message you are referring to but if you mean a you want to show a popup just create a `UIAlertView` and show it when the button is clicked in the cell.

However, if you mean change a UIlabel text or whatever as a message on the ViewController you can always pass whatever you need to change into the TableView and Cell or the `UIViewController` itself into it.

I usually create a method on the custom cells class and pass it whatever I need into the custom TableView's constructor. Then in the TableView's `GetCell()` method pass whatever I need to change into that method I created on the cell and save it as a variable on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you've initiated your UITableViewCell, and added a button to the cell, you can use a Delegate when the button is clicked, something like this:

```
UIButton button = new UIButton (cell.Bounds.X, cell.Bounds.y, cell.Bounds.Width, cell.Bounds.Height);
button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
    label.text = "Blablabla";
};
```

Where the label is, is up to you. I hope this helps, good luck!